# Phpmyadmin Relations between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make relations between a new table and a wordpress woocommerce table "wp_posts" by making a foreign key constraint from the new table to the ID of wp_posts, I managed to make the constraint but it still only returns null to me, it looks like this [image: the constraint looks like this]

it should display an ID from wp_posts with that FK but nothing happened.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by 'I managed to make the constraint but it still only returns null to me,'

Comment: I got the ID to be a foreign key, but it still doesn't exactly return me anything to the foreign key column

Comment: Not with you , a foreign key is a constraint it doesn't fetch anything from another table it checks for existence in another table on an insert.

Comment: oh, I see, so if I try to select the field it would check its existence on the other table?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do but no a select won't check for existence on other table you maybe need a join to do that. Foreign keys only come in to play on inserts, updates and deletes..

Comment: @P.Salmon I want to check for data with the ID from wp_posts and use it do display data from another table without actually adding the same ID into the other table